# unable to push docker image using github actions

Tags: java, docker, github, github-actions

I am trying to create a docker image and push it on github.
here's my `main.yml`

```
name: Docker

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  # TODO: Change variable to your image's name.
  IMAGE_NAME: java-app

jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build --file ./docker/Dockerfile --tag ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} .

      - name: Log into registry
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }} registry.hub.docker.com
  
      - name: Push image
        run: |
          IMAGE_ID=${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/qfix-test
          # Strip git ref prefix from version
          VERSION=$(echo "${{ github.ref }}" | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
          # Strip "v" prefix from tag name
          [[ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/tags/"* ]] && VERSION=$(echo $VERSION | sed -e 's/^v//')
          # Use Docker `latest` tag convention
          [ "$VERSION" == "master" ] && VERSION=latest
          echo IMAGE_ID=$IMAGE_ID
          echo VERSION=$VERSION

          docker tag ${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
          docker push $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
```

Here's the error:

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/***/java-app]
d1eab8b60748: Waiting
unauthorized: access token has insufficient scopes
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have created 2 secrets one with dockerhub_username, dockerhub_password which has the access token with read, write and delete permissions. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Does that user has the right permissions i.e. `push`?

Comment: I figured it out! I was using wrong method to login. That does not work. I checked this guide: https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/ and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
The issue was that it was the wrong way to login.
The correct way is:

```
   -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

As soon as I replaced this `run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }} registry.hub.docker.com` with the above login it worked!

Details can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/