# Unable to push docker image from github codespaces using skaffold

Tags: docker, skaffold, github-codespaces

I'm trying to push an image using skaffold on codespaces but am getting this error: `unauthorized: access token has insufficient scopes`. I see something similar for github actions but am unsure how this works in github codespaces. [unable to push docker image using github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556121/unable-to-push-docker-image-using-github-actions)